# An error occurred while collecting items to be installed artifact

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

I have a problem regarding intallation of new software in my eclipse RCP.

I developped some plugin with Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers (Version: Mars.2 Realse 4.5.2). I have created a feature and include some of my plugin in it.

When I export my feature, eclipse create an "artifacts.jar", a "content.jar" and 2 other folders (features and plugins).

Then, I tried to install it on my eclipse RCP to test it. So I go on "Help"/"Install New Software..."
I clic on "Add..." then I select "Archive..." and I give him the "content.jar"

Here, I have to deselect "Group items by category" to see my plugins. Then I selected them and clic "Next>". Then "Finish" but I have an error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw0Ne.png)

It says that no artifact repo are available.

I do not understand why as there is an artifacts.jar in my folder...

If someone gets an idea???

Thank you very much
(sorry for my bad english, furthermore I'm new in coding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the "artifacts.jar", a "content.jar" in a **folder** you are not installing an Archive. The Archive install is for a single file containing all of the install files.

Choose 'Local' instead of 'Archive' in the 'Install New Software' 'Add...' dialog and choose the folder containing the jars.